# Hacer Auto-Height de DataGridView de acuerdo a las Filas

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2013

Necesito poder **acomodar** la altura del `FORM` o del `DataGridView` según la cantidad de datos/filas que se llenaron en el `DataGrid`.

Esto **teniendo en cuenta** que casos en los que hay cuatro filas, y otros que solo hay dos filas o tres, **donde** queda un espacio en blanco que no ocupan las filas del `DataGridView`.

***Ejemplo 1***:
En este ejemplo, la consulta devuelve cuatro filas, y el espacio queda casi completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Ejemplo 2***: En este ejemplo la consulta devuelve solo tres filas y el espacio es muchísimo más grande:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que, **sin importar si la consulta devuelve *"n"* números de filas**, el espacio sea el **exacto para que todas las filas se vean al instante**, entonces, no haya necesidad de usar `ScrollBar`

**¿Cómo podría lograr esto?**

**EDIT:**

> **SOLUCIÓN**

De antemano muchas gracias a los que participaron y me ayudaron :D

*Se comparte el código logrado:*

Código en `C#`

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Función que se encarga de redimencionar el alto del formulario deacuerdo a la cantidad de datos que posee el datagrid view
        /// </summary>
        private void RedimencionarForm()
        {
            int AltoGridIni = Grid_Datos.Height;
            int AltoGrid = 0;
            int AltoForm = this.Height;
            int Diferencia = 0;
            AltoGrid = AltoGrid + Grid_Datos.ColumnHeadersHeight;

            for (int i = 0; i <= Grid_Datos.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                AltoGrid = AltoGrid + Grid_Datos.Rows[i].Height;
            }
            Diferencia = AltoGridIni - AltoGrid;

            if (Diferencia > 0)
            {
                AltoForm = AltoForm - Diferencia;
                this.Height = AltoForm;
            }
            else if (Diferencia < 0)
            {
                AltoForm = AltoForm + Diferencia;
                this.Height = AltoForm;
            }
            Grid_Datos.Height = AltoGrid;
        }
```

Comment: Me imagino una división, algo como alturaDatagrid/CantidadFilas = alturaFila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a tu inconveniente puede encontrarse en el código que te voy a compartir, solo que mirando las imágenes que compartiste obviamente es necesario que adecues el código a tus necesidades.

```
Dim DT_Prueba As New DataTable
DT_Prueba.Columns.Add("Dato")

' Teniendo el DataTable que tienes cargado previamente en tu DataGridView   '
' Este paso no es necesario que lo coloques ya que solo lleno un DataTable  '
' con Información y lo asigno al DataGridView                               '

For x = 0 To 10
    DT_Prueba.Rows.Add(x)
Next

DataGridView1.DataSource = DT_Prueba

' Aqui comienza el código de interés                                        '
' Defino una variable para almacenar el alto final del Grid                 '
Dim AltoDelGrid As Integer

' Sumo el alto de la fila que representa el encabezado de las Columnas      '
AltoDelGrid = AltoDelGrid + DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight

' Ahora recorro el DataGridView y sumo el alto de cada fila                 '
For x = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    AltoDelGrid = AltoDelGrid + DataGridView1.Rows(x).Height
Next


' Finalmente asigno el valor de la variable al alto del control             '
DataGridView1.Height = AltoDelGrid
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó, publico el código que hice por si a alguien más le puede servir, además, coloco el código en `C#`